# How do I set ListBox item height in Window Resources?

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

This

```
<ListBox x:Name="gLBxM">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="21" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

sets the ListBox item height for a specific ListBox.  What do add to

```
<Window.Resources>
```

so it applies to all ListBox'es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implicit `Style` will be applied to all `ListBoxItems` in the window unless you set the `ItemContainerStyle` property to some other `Style`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ListBox x:Name="gLBxM" />
```